# String user input validation

Tags: java

How to construct a test to ensure that the user has provided a decimal point somewhere within the string?

Comment: Downvoting (or voting to close) the question, without a comment does not help the poster improve the question.

Comment: -1 For poor sentence construction and lack of detail. Also, is this a homework problem?

Comment: @RyanAmos, The question is simple and straight forward. What detail are you expecting? We have two great answers based on the current wording of the question.

Comment: @camickr It would have been nice to see that the OP had shown us an example of their attempts and where they are stuck. That way, the OP can get the most help possible.

Comment: @RyanAmos, again then point  that in your original comment. We are not mind readers, we don't know what you are thinking when you downvote. Its the posters first question and they can't improve without detailed comments.

Comment: @camickr That was the first time I have ever downvoted. I tried to be as clear as I could.

Answer (score 5):

Use indexOf(".") method to check whether the string contains a decimal point.
Eg:

```
String str = "232.3";
if(str.indexOf(".") != -1)
{
   // Contains a decimal point
}
else {
   // Does not
}
```

Comment: Yeah, or you could write your own search loop with a for each. Best to use your own method unless you know theirs is better.

Comment: @RyanAmos, that is a terrible suggestion to write your own loop. Use methods that exist in the API and DON'T reivent the wheel.

Comment: @camickr For something as simple as this, I don't think that it is necessarily bad. You're maximizing efficiency. While in a homework problem like this, it probably doesn't matter, you don't know what methods String.indexOf() uses to get information. It could be using a loop, as we expect, or it could be doing something extra we don't need. Seeing as String.indexOf() replies with an integer, not a boolean, it is checking for more than we need, which is just the verification of the existence of something.

Comment: @camickr I also think that beginners really ought to reinvent the wheel a few times for practice. There's a lot to be learned from reinventing the wheel, hence why programming classes go through creating data structures like linked lists, hash tables, etc.

Comment: @RyanAmos, then post your own answer suggestion your looping solution. There is no need for a comment in this suggestion since you are changing the concept of the answer completely. The answer given here is "first check out methods in the API". Your suggestion is "write looping code from scratch".

Comment: just wondering, why -1 ?

Comment: studying for a first course java exam tomorrow :P

Comment: != -1 , why is that -1 there?

Comment: Read the API. It explains how the indexOf() method works and what the value returned from the method means.

Comment: -1 is returned by the method when the input doesn't exist in the string. -1 is standard for "no result" when null is not an option.

Comment: Being a bad programmer - should read the API when I need to know the parameters. Thanks guys :)

Comment: @RyanAmos, re "it is checking for more than we need" -- have you taken a look at the `String.indexOf` implementation? For characters that can be represented with a single `char` (and `.` is one of them), the method does exactly two bits of extra work, both of which are just a `<` comparison. Essentially zero extra work. The reason it returns the index, rather than just a boolean, is that the index is readily available from the loop it would anyway have to do.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [contains](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) functions.

```
public boolean contains(CharSequence s)
```

Comment: +1, interesting approach if you don't care where the decimal is found.

Answer (score 2):

```
String userInput="123.23";

if(userInput!=null && unserInput.indexOf('.')!=-1)
{
   //contains decimal point
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this would be with a for each loop

```
char desiredCharacter = '.';
String myStr = getString(); //get a string somehow
boolean b = false;
for(char c : myStr.toCharArray())
    if(c == desiredCharacter){
        b = true;
        break;
    }
if(b){
    //Character is in the string
}
else{
    //Character is not in the string
}
```

This way, you don't have to deal with possible inefficiencies brought up by external methods. Plus, the practice of writing your own methods is good for development--we wouldn't want our brains to turn to mush, would we?

Comment: If you're worried about inefficiency, isn't the way to go. toCharArray() copies the internal `char[]` (it has to, in order to maintain String's immutability).

Comment: Yes, I suppose you could use Reflection to gain internal access to the String. I don't think that would be much faster, though. I suppose iterating through the individual characters with charAt() might be faster. Also, toCharArray() uses System.arrayCopy(), which is native, greatly improving efficiency.

Comment: Um, copying an array and then iterating over it (your approach) is never going to be faster than simply iterating over the original (what String.charAt does). Adding reflection could take away some of the cost (though it may reduce some optimizations, not sure), but now you're going out of your way to reinvent a wheel that really doesn't need reinventing. It's one thing to say "it's good to write your own as a coding exercise," but let's not pretend there's any other reason to do it.